# How to give focus() after an alert()?

Tags: javascript, html, events, focus

I have something like:

```
<input type="textbox" id="partNumber" onChange="validatePart(this);">
<input type="textbox" id="quantity" onfocus="saveOldQuantity(this);">
```

The `onChange` event is properly firing after a change is made *and* the textbox loses focus. When `quantity` gains focus, the `onfocus` event is properly firing to save the old value of `quantity` before changes are made.

If `validatePart()` detects an invalid `partNumber` value, it `alert`s the user to that fact. After the `alert()` has cleared, I'd like to return focus to the `partNumber` input. But doing a `focus()` on the input node is not giving it focus. Debugging is tricky here, because the IE debug window interaction is, of course, changing the focus.

How can I ensure focus returns to `partNumber` if an error is detected in `validatePart()`?

EDIT:
A simple version of `validatePart()`:

```
function validatePart(node) {
    if (!node.value) {
        alert('Please enter a part number.');
        node.focus();   // <======= why isn't this having any effect??
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try a small timeout before setting the focus?

Comment: It's not that the screen is freezing. The focus goes to wherever the user has clicked or tabbed to. I need to somehow cancel that action and override it to return focus to `partNumber`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can prevent the user from selecting another tab. I personally wouldn't prefer that, either.

Comment: @pimvdb: Maybe it's not so much cancelling, but more like the same as when you load a page and give focus to a node using `node.focus();`. For some reason the `focus()` method is not working here.

Comment: @pimvdb: Tell me a bit more about how you're thinking `setTimeout` might help here. Maybe I'm thinking about it wrongly.

Comment: I've had some problems with focusing, so suspending it for some time helped sometimes. So e.g. please try `setTimeout(function() { node.focus(); }, 500);`.

Comment: @pimvdb: That was it. You had it from the beginning. Thanks much!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding a small timeout and resetting the focus back to the `partNumber` textbox should do the trick.

Thus your `validatePart()` function becomes something like:

```
function validatePart(node) {
    if (!node.value) {
        alert('Please enter a part number.');
        setTimeout(function(){node.focus();}, 1);
    }
}
```

[Here's a quick "live" example](http://jsbin.com/uvijeh) that simply fires an `alert` no matter what is entered into the `partNumber` textbox and successfully returns focus back to the `partNumber` textbox (even if you tab off it to the `quantity` textbox.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout` (it gets `eval`d), pass a function.  `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("partNumber").focus();}, 1);`

Comment: @Rocket - You're right.  I've amended my answer to reflect a more technically correct version by passing in a function to the `setTimeout` function, rather than a string that needs to be `eval`d before being executed.

Comment: @CraigTP: A 1 millisecond timeout worked for me. BTW, I just used a generic `function()` as the first parameter. Thanks!

Comment: Using `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(node.id).focus();}, 1);` worked for me. Didn't work without document.getElementById

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work as expected for me. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/vWEDB/). Are you seeing some other behavior? I see that I type a number in textbox1. Then when I tab over to textbox2 I get `Invalid Part!` error and focus stays on current textbox.

Updated - Since this only seems to play nice in Chrome you could keep track of whether an error exists. If so then handle it.

```
var error = null;
function checkForErrors() { 
   if (error) { error.focus(); error = null; }            
}

function validatePart(node) {
   if (badpart) { error = node; }
}

function saveOldQuantity(node) {
   checkForErrors();
}
```

Comment: Okay, looks like this doesn't work in IE9 or FF. Works fine in Chrome. Will look a little bit more.

Comment: @Jonathan M - Updated my answer with a non settimeout answer. I always like to try and avoid those. I wish it could be as elegant as just `node.focus()` but the events play out in the wrong order for that to work.

Comment: But if order of events is a concern, won't `saveOldQuantity` call `checkForErrors` before `validatePart` has a chance to assign `error`?

Comment: Order of events was a concern calling `.focus()` from within validatePart. Now I move that call into the focus of saveOldQuantity. So order of events has been solved.

Comment: Ah, yes. I understand. The only thing that steers me from this approach is the use of a global (`error`). But, I definitely like the non-time-dependent approach. Have an upvote. :)