# Javascript - set focus after alert message

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tryng to focus on the same element when validation fail. Here's my HTML code :

`<input 
id="potatoes" name="potatoes" value="" type="text" class="tooltip" 
onblur="Validate('potatoes')" autocomplete='off'>`

and here's my javascript code :

```
function Validate(id) {
var errors = {
    potatoes : 'enter potatoes',
    hamburgers : 'enter'
};
if (document.getElementById(id).value === '') {
    if (id in errors) {
        alert(errors[id]);
         //setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(id).focus();}, 1);
    }
}
```

}

I've tried to set focus using .focus() method but it doesn't work. I've read that it might depend on "onblur" in HTML, when I call my function Validate(), so i've tried to change it but nothing worked till now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give focus() after an alert()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234190/how-to-give-focus-after-an-alert)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a problem here. This code is going in loop. When 'focus' is triggered, the function Validate is called again, showing another alert dialog.

That's a working code

**HTML**

`<input id="potatoes" name="potatoes" value="" type="text" class="tooltip" onblur="Validate(this)" autocomplete='off'>`

**Javascript**

```
var validating = false; //<-- IMPORTANT
function Validate(element) {
var id = element.id;

var errors = {
    potatoes : 'enter potatoes',
    hamburgers : 'enter'
};
if (document.getElementById(id).value === '') {
    if (id in errors) {
            if(validating == false) {
                    validating = true
            alert(errors[id]);
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById(id).focus();
                validating = false;
            }, 1);
            }
    }
}
}
```

In the html I'm passing **this**, doing so I'm passing the element and in the Validate function you can access to the id just calling

```
var id = element.id;
```

For the focus problem (caused by a loop problem) as you can see I'm using a **validating** variable to know when is validating when is not. This let **Validate** function avoids to go in loop.
So:

1) Define a **validating** var **outside** the Validate function and set it to false.

2) Fire the **focus** and **alert** only if **validating** is false, and after that set it to **true**

Answer (score 3):

The javascript function `alert(string)` is synchronous. The script is paused while the user is reacting to the alerted message. There is no need to do something special. The following snippet should work:

```
alert(errors[id]);
document.getElementById(id).focus();
```

The element got focus directly after the user has submitted the alerted message.

Comment: `alert(string)` is not asynchronous it is synchronous so script waits until the alert diaolog to be closed to keep on

Comment: Just misspelled it... Thanks

Comment: @HarshJaswal - This behavior is called 'recursion'. It happens, because you bound the `onblur` event. There, you call the `focus()` method. This will result in a never ending loop.

Comment: So how can i focus after `alert`? And thanks for the quick response

Comment: @HarshJaswal You are focusing after the alert. But I assume that this triggers the onblur event.

Comment: Yes i do agree with you. But `el.focus();` should run only after the alert dialog box is closed. So after closing the alert box if i am clicking on the screen(not in the textbox), then only `onblur` should get called. Am I right?

Comment: @HarshJaswal - Have a look at [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJmawv?editors=1111). Maybe this resolves your problem. Otherwise you should explain your goal :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like this:

`setTimeout(function() {$('#yourInputId').focus();},1);`